# Javascript FileAPI XSLT file object to string?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, activex, fileapi

I have in a way a two part question. The first part, is it possible to use the new FileAPI to retrieve the full path of an item? So far I have this:

```
var file;
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    file = files[0];
}
```

The file variable then needs to go into this function:

```
function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc(file);
xsl = loadXMLDoc("linkto.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

But unfortunately doing this passes it as a file object and according to the documentation all I can find is file.name. But, this is not the full path which is what needs to go in there. So is there a way to get the full path?

If not, is there a way to adapt this function to accept a file object instead of a string?

Comment: you can turn a file object into a url using window.URL.createObjectURL(theBlobOrFile). you should them be able to ajax the xml document from the url, but i doubt such a thing can be done in older IE. you can also use FileReader() to turn the file into a string and use string-based XSLT methods, though that breaks some xsl linking features (if used).

Comment: Thanks for the response @dandavis, I added that code and nothing happened. So I'm not sure if it just didn't read correctly or just doesn't accept that kind of url? Or did it just not get passed correctly to my function? EDIT: I dont' think its getting into my function because I tried setting the inner text from within my function and it didn't work. What do I need to do to get it to go to that function? When in a file by itself it just works right away.

Comment: add "displayResult()" to the bottom of handleFileSelect() to call the xslt part after the file slect part is done.

Comment: Alright I added that line and added this simple test line to the beginning of the function displayResult() and I got nothing. document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "hi";

Comment: you can always try the loadXMLString() routines further down the w3fools page...